# ??? like function in Scala

Tags: scala, guice

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L230

??? in scala is a function defined in predef that throws a NotImplementedError

In my project I am using Google Guice in order to inject dependencies, and thought it would be good to have a similar function that throws an exception if the injection never happened, in order to catch missing usages of the injector or missing @Inject annotations.

In my project I have a class that is expecting to be injected

```
class OScoreboard {
  @Inject
  val source :Provider[ScoreboardBuilder] = injected;
}
```

and an object

```
class ExpectedInjectionException(message: String = null, cause: Throwable = null) extends RuntimeException

object injected extends Nothing{
  def apply : Nothing = {
    throw new ExpectedInjectionException("Expected an injection")
  }
}
```

But I get the error that injected isn't of type Provider[ScoreboardBuilder]

Am I abusing apply? How else can I reference the scala function apply (or even with a different name) without referencing the object injected?

Also I suspect that even if I fix this error, the function will be eagerly run causing the exception before injection happens, does that mean I need to make every injected field lazy, or is there another solution?

**Edit:**

---

The problem was my understanding of Scala.

vals are eagerly computed, so the ???-like function is immediately executed on class construction (which since it's using field injection, occurs immediately before injection happens) causing the field to never be injected.

Values like final fields in Java **CAN** be injected, because it's only a restriction by the byte code verifier. final fields can be written to fine by using **reflection** (which **Guice** does).

In order to answer this question there needs to be a way to delay the execution of the ???-like function/value until the field is first read. I'm unsure how, or if it is even possible. The other option is just to initialize them to null. But that will result in NullPointerExceptions which are famously unhelpful. I was hoping to use a null-like error with an explanation that the injection failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my understanding of Scala.

vals are eagerly computed, so the ??? function is immediately executed on class construction (which since it's using field injection, occurs immediately before injection happens) causing the exception to be thrown.

Making it lazy results in the injection happening using reflection without the exception being thrown on construction. HOWEVER the generated Java code is not aware that this happens. So when the injected value is accessed for the first time, the generated code replaces the injected reference with ??? then proceeds to throw the exception.

There is no way that I can see in order to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: in one place you wrote `INJECTED` and in the other place `injected`. I'll assume this was a typo and that you mean the same thing with both.

An assignment like this:

```
val source :Provider[ScoreboardBuilder] = INJECTED;
```

will not work because you are trying to assign the object `INJECTED` to a variable of type `Provider[ScoreboardBuilder]`. The object is not of that type, so you can't do that assignment.

Maybe you expected that the object would behave like a function and that its `apply` method would automatically be called, but that's not how it works.

You can define `INJECTED` as a method inside your class:

```
class OScoreboard {
  @Inject
  val source :Provider[ScoreboardBuilder] = INJECTED

  private def INJECTED : Nothing =
    throw new ExpectedInjectionException("Expected an injection")
}
```

Or you can put it in a separate object, but then you'd have to import it in your class:

```
object injected {
  def INJECTED : Nothing =
    throw new ExpectedInjectionException("Expected an injection")
}

class OScoreboard {
  import injected._

  @Inject
  val source :Provider[ScoreboardBuilder] = INJECTED
}
```

Comment: Ah! so it's not enough to import it into the file, but you would also need to import it into the class.

Also you have capitalized the function as INJECTED, which is what I had before I tried swapping it to apply :) thanks.

Comment: I accepted this too soon. I'll accept this as the answer if I fail to run into any problems with the function evaluating before the injection happens.

Comment: Ok, I've gotten around to testing this and it doesn't work as expected.

As far as I can tell, it immediately errors as soon as the class is constructed/injected, as opposed to waiting until the fields are accessed.

It was probably my assumption that ??? doesn't immediately error, but is there a way to fix this or delay the exception until the field is accessed?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Note that a `val` in a class is initialized when you create an instance of the class (when the constructor runs) and it can only be initialized once. So, you can't first initialize it with something like `INJECTED` and then let some dependency injection mechanism modify it. Like `final` member variable in Java. You'd have to use constructor argument injection.